# How to do action using Button in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i have a button that i create in my CustomCell.

```
- (IBAction)onoffBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if (button.selected)
    {
        // Do action 1
    }
    else
    {
        // Do action 2
    }
}
```

When i run it, the button is show in my cell inside UITableView that i create in TableViewController. I can press that onoffBtn inside my cell but it cant do action. How do i do so that my button can do action?

this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath inside my TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _customCell;
        _customCell = nil;
    }
    // Show my cell
    return cell;
}
```

and for other question, where should i write for do process at? inside my TableViewController.m or my CustomCell.m? if you dont mind, please provide me with code and explanation, im new in here and still learning. i want to understand in every line of code that you write. Thank you.

Update:

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath inside TableViewController.m so far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _customCell;
        _customCell = nil;
    }
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.titleLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timerLabel.text =  [timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    time = [[secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Title %@, time %@, second %@, time %i, tag %d", titleArray, timeArray, secondArray, time, button.tag);
    return cell;
}
```

and this is log said:

```
2012-08-04 17:38:36.257 Table[1269:f803] Title (
    "Test 1",
    "Test 2"
), time (
    "10 secs",
    "5 secs"
), second (
    10,
    5
), time 10, tag 0 // tag 0 for cell 1
2012-08-04 17:38:36.261 Table[1269:f803] Title (
    "Test 1",
    "Test 2"
), time (
    "10 secs",
    "5 secs"
), second (
    10,
    5
), time 5, tag 0 // tag should be 1 for cell 2 but it said 0. How to fix it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS IS HOW YOU ADD BUTTON WITH AN ACTION IN A CELL

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// ADDING A BUTTON WITH TARGET
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
btn.tag = indexPath.row;
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onoffBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

return cell;
}


- (IBAction)onoffBtn:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = !button.selected;
if (button.selected)
{
    // Do action 1
}
else
{
    // Do action 2
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, im beginner. Can i ask something? I already put a button inside my CustomCell, should i add a button again using your code? Thank you very much

Comment: you can Remove your button and add this code this will dynamically add a button to all the cells according to frame set or if your cells are constant and you have added buttons by your self via xib you can simply connect the same IBAction to all the buttons in xib file

Comment: Sir, i already remove it but i can connect my button with my code and i put button.tag = indexPath.row; inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath and NSLog. but when i run it with 2 cells inside my tableview, both tag number showed by NSLog is 0, not 0 and 1. Am i forget something? Please teach, how to make my button can set right tag?

Comment: can you  please tell me what are you trying to achieve may be i can send you a demo and please don't call me sir :) i am also a learner :)

Comment: i mean i already remove my UIButton code inside CustomCell.m but i already connected the button inside CustomCell.xib into my code onoffBtn inside my TableViewController.m  also i put button.tag = indexPath.row; inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath and NSLog. but when i run it with 2 cells inside my tableview, both tag number showed by NSLog is 0, not 0 and 1. Please teach. I hope you understand my english, because english is not my native language.

Comment: Make sure you have connected your IBOutlet UIButton *button to the button you added in xib for this go to your xid control click your file owner and drag it to the button you added and select the IBOutlet... give me your email id i have made a demo for you .. how to use tableview and how you can use custom cell with least efforts