# Tag for tableviewcell showing wrong value

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

This is my tableview that I made so far

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titleArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _customCell;
        _customCell = nil;
    }
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.titleLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timerLabel.text =  [timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    time = [[secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Title %@, time %@, second %@, time %i, tag %d", titleArray, timeArray, secondArray, time, button.tag);
    return cell;
}
```

and this is my button that I made so far

```
- (IBAction)onoffBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"My tag is %d time %i, tag %d",indexPath.row, time, button.tag);
}
```

when I run it, I put 3 cells with different value for each data and my log showing like this below

```
2012-08-05 16:32:59.224 Schedule[960:f803] Title (
    "Title 1",
    "Test 2",
    "Test 3"
), time (
    "5 secs",
    "10 secs",
    "15 secs"
), second (
    5,
    10,
    15
), time 15, tag 2

// after I push onoffBtn, my log is showing below

2012-08-05 16:33:01.409 Schedule[960:f803] My tag is 0 time 15, tag 2
2012-08-05 16:33:05.042 Schedule[960:f803] My tag is 1 time 15, tag 2
2012-08-05 16:33:07.113 Schedule[960:f803] My tag is 2 time 15, tag 2
```

for tag both tag showing wrong result for time and tag, that is 15 and 2. how to fix it? if you don't mind, please provide code and explanation because I want to understand.

Comment: What are 'button' and 'time' in the code?

Comment: Ah, probably the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806892/how-to-do-action-using-button-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806892/how-to-do-action-using-button-in-uitableviewcell is also my question but this time is different with that question. but i think, theres not about my button or time code. both button and time code is only iboutlet and input from my customcell. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong is that you created the button using a custom UITableViewCell in a nib file in XCode, then you wired that button up to a property of your view-controller class.

This won't work the way you want because there is only one property in your class, but there are many rows in your table.  So you get the symptoms you see.

The technique recommended by Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) is to give each element you added in the nib file a unique tag (e.g. your button is tag 1) and then fetch it using `viewWithTag:`